# mysqli_connect function is not giving expected error message?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm newbie in php and learning it from thenewboston Youtube channel. Problem is I wrote very basic code for database connectivity in php and for generating error message, purposely I provide null or false values in "mysqli_connect()" fucntion. But the problem is even the values are not correct, it is not showing error message while in the tutorial, from which I am learning there is an error message for wrong parameters however in the tutorial "mysql_connect()" function is used instead of "mysqli_connect()". Please help!!

```
<?php
$mysqli_host = '';  //localhost
$mysqli_user = '';  //root
$mysqli_pass = '';  //NULL

mysqli_connect($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass) or die('Could not connect!!');

echo 'Connected!!';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

> ```
> passwd
> ```
>
> If not provided or `NULL`, the MySQL server will attempt to authenticate the user against those user records which have no password only. This allows one username to be used with different permissions (depending on if a password as provided or not).

**It is not an error to pass `NULL` as the password.**